# Making EntityFramework set one property first, before the others

Tags: entity-framework, properties

When using code-first EntityFramework, I need one property to be set before the others - how do I specify the order that it calls the property sets, when it is creating the objects from the database?

E.g.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Something 
    { 
        get { return something; } 
        set
        {
             something = value + " for " + Name;
        }
    }

    private string something;
}
```

In the code above, I need the Name property to already have been set by the time it sets the Something property.

This isn't the actual example - I know there are other ways to achieve that literally, but I'm not after those, just how I can tell EF to set Name before Something.

Comment: perhaps you can post a real example.  This one doesn't make any sense because you are not using the value passed to the setter.

Comment: it didn't, sorry!  now edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to understand the context of your question. I am going to make the assumptions that:

1. The value passed to the setter is not another calculated property
2. the value passed to the setter is intended to be stored in the database
3. If name is updated you would want  Something to be updated to reflect the new name?

I think your mistake here is trying to add a derived portion to the value you are looking to store. Calculate the pretty name in another property, or on a get:

**UPDATE** had an example overriding the get on the Something Property, but removed as I feel it is bad practice.

```
public class Person
{
public string Name { get; set; }

public string Something { get; set; }

public string getFancySomething { 
    { return Something + " for " + Name; } 
}
}
```

Finally - (and here is where I could use some help as I have not run into a situation where I needed to do something like this) my guess is that you do not need to be storing the partially calculated property `Something` in the way you were attempting, but if you do need to, I think additional detail might help someone provide you with a better answer.

**UPDATE 2**
As described in my comments - not sure this would work, and it feels very wrong, but you could try something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Ignore(x => x.Something);
```

and then in the setter:

```
public class Person
{
public string Name { 
   get { return Name; }
   set { 
       Name = value;

       Something = lookup();
    }
}
}
```

Again this will depend on you needs, and would not satisfy any need to pass this value in, and I am not sure this is a great idea.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this, but the "derived" aspect is not relevant, I'm just trying to get it to set the properties in a particular order, and my example just serves to demonstrate why I might want to.  Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know of any way. If there is something you can do about this it would be somehow defining it in Fluent... but it is beyond my understanding. That said, the question really begs for more detail to see if you can avoid this problem with design. For example can the things you want to force to load second be a part of a separate entity and then you can control within your business logic the order in which they are loaded? Is there another way to accomplish what you want without caring about this?  Sorry I can't provide a more helpful or confident yes/no.

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is telling modelbuilder to ignore the second property and then writing the logic to get and set it within the setter of the one you want to be loaded first. But that feels very wrong. Example above.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, I had a quick look at Fluent - it doesn't look like it will do it. I think I have to do one of your suggestions - either design the problem out, or read some of the properties manually, without EF.  You mention controlling the order different entities are loaded, using business logic - can you elaborate on that?

Comment: This depends on your design and what you are actually doing: could you have two objects, one which has all the fields you require to be loaded first (or don't care) and a second with the secondary fields - then ensure the order these are loaded each time you use them in your application. It is not enforced for you by the Entity but might solve your problem. At this point without the actual use cases in question it requires making too many assumptions to provide a meaningful answer I'm afraid. If you can add detail there are people here with more EF experience than me who might help.

Comment: Thanks for your help Matthew - again, I'm not sure how I would "ensure the order these are loaded each time you use them in your application" - in principle, how is this done?  With data attributes?  Fluent?  Or do you mean outside of EF? If so, then how are you thinking it would be done please?

Comment: I mean outside of EF, just actually load these two objects separately in your code when using them and check / set one before the other. As you indicated above, this may not solve your problem, but without knowing more about what you are attempting it is difficult to suggest a workaround for it.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your help - I have found another way (I think!), which basically doesn't assume any of the properties are "loaded" by EF until they all are.  So I'm adding a method to each object which I will call after EF has set them all up, and the objects will then do the remaining initialisation.  Basically your answer "you can't" is the right one, at least for me!  Thanks again.